# c language for-loop create thread

Tags: c, for-loop, pthreads

I want make a 5 threads using a `for`-loop like this,

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   pthread_create(...., NULL, printHelloWorld, (void *)&i);
}

void printHelloWorld(void *arg){
   printf("%d\n", *(int *)arg);
}
```

//in this code

1. i=0
2. thread create -> printHelloWorld
3. i++ (i=1);  -> by for loop
4. I print arg in printHelloWorld. I think arg is 0 but in result arg is 1;

//so I think use array -> but use 20byte memory.

//I want to use memory smaller than 20byte.
Do you have a good ideas?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Also, what have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: You're using POSIX threads in an environment where 20 bytes is a serious problem?   I think you've got your priorities mixed up.

Comment: The type `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>` (or `<inttypes.h>`) is big enough to hold a pointer (if it is defined at all; it is theoretically optional, and wouldn't be defined if there isn't an integer type suitable for holding object pointers — as opposed to function pointers).  You could, therefore, use `int errnum; for (uintptr_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) { if ((errnum = pthread_create(…, (void *)i)) != 0) { …handle error… } }`, and in the thread function `void *thread_func(void *args) { uintptr_t i = (uintptr_t)args; …; return 0; }` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you are asking, why the first thread gets a value of 1 from `i` instead of the expected 0.

The reason for this is, that you pass a reference to `i`. Every change to `i` is a change to everyone who has a reference to there. You have to create a copy for each thread.

This leads to another problem of your code: If the threads run longer than the creation code, `i` will be lost in memory and the passed reference are invalid. You should do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  int *arg = malloc( sizeof int ); // Likely you want to have a bigger structure.
  *arg = i;
  pthread_create(...., NULL, function, arg );
}
```

Typed in Safari.

`function()` has to free the allocated memory at its end.

```
void *function( void *param ) 
{
  int i = *param;
  free( param );
  …
}
```

Comment: I think the core diagnosis is probably correct (the value `&i` is not private to each thread so it changes incorrectly), but if 20 bytes for an array was a problem, 5 memory allocations, each of which will probably require at least 8 bytes on a 32-bit system and probably 16 bytes on a 64-bit system, is not a step in the right direction.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   int *arg = malloc( sizeof int ); // Likely you want to have a bigger structure.
   arg = i;
   pthread_create(...., NULL, printHelloWorld, (void *)&i);
   free(arg);
}

void printHelloWorld(void *arg){
   printf("%d\n", *(int *)arg);
} you want to say like this??

Comment: It is hard to read code inside a comment. However, I had a typo in my answer, that I corrected.